# Real-time plot in Simulink with data from the workspace and the simulation

Tags: matlab, plot, real-time, simulink

I have a simulation of an aircraft, and I'm trying to plot it's intended trajectory and the actual flightpath in a plot.

Initially I was using a XY Graph block from Simulink, but it doesn't allow to show a second signal in the background. So I thought about using an Interpreted MATLAB Function block and plot the two things there.

I have an initialization M-file where I define the vectors x_t and y_t, the coordinates of the trajectory, and open the figure. I make those two global variables and the function in Simulink receives them, together with x_e and y_e from the simulation.

Now the problem is that it gets really slow, so much I can't actually control the aircraft properly. Any suggestions on how to achieve my goal? I appreciate your help.

Below I have put the code I'm using for that purpose, so that you can see the whole picture. By the way, 'i' is a variable being used to store data into vectors and is being incremented in another function.

```
*** Initialization.m ***

% The definition of x_1:x_5 and y_1:y_5 has been omitted.

x_t=[x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5];
y_t=[y_1 y_2 y_3 y_4 y_5];

figure(1);

---------------------------- 

*** Flightpath.m ***

function Flightpath(u)

%% Variables
%%
global i x_t y_t x_e y_e;

x_e(i)=u(1); y_e(i)=u(2);

%% Real-Time Graphic
%%
t=plot(x_t,y_t,20000,10000,'ro',x_e,y_e);
axis([-5000 25000 -5000 50000]); set(t,'MarkerFaceColor','r');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things that you should change,

1. You are growing the size of x_e and y_e at each time step.  That is always bad, and will slow things down considerably.  (I recognize that you may not know the final size in advance, but that doesn't negate the fact that growing it at each step is bad.)
2. You are using `plot`, a high level routine, when lower level functionality would suffice.
3. You are plotting x_t and y_t at each time step, when it only needs to be plotted once.
4. You should plot (possibly dummy data containing only 2 points) for x_e and y_e at time 0 with the line visibility turned off, and store the line handle.  Then at each time step you should just get the XData and YData for the line, and replace it with new XData and YData that contains the new data the current time point.
5. You would have much finer control of what's happening by writing an M-code S-Function that just using the Interpreted Function block.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is concise and well explained. I would like to discuss these points with you.
1. I agree with you, it was something that was bugging me. I decided to set a fix time for the simulation, run it and check the maximum value of 'i' to preallocate these vectors, together with many others. By the way, a bit off topic but what is more optimal (considering speed but not disregarding space), to define x=zeros(c_1,c_2) and then say x_e=x and y_e=x or put directly x_e=zeros(c_1,c_2) and y_e=zeros(c_1,c_2)?

Comment: 2. I guess this one and 4 are connected, so the idea is to change the plot strategy to the line option, sounds interesting. Can you help me a bit with the implementation? I always struggle with object handles and their manipulation, such as this.
3. I was reflecting on this and arrived at the same conclusion, so this is taken care of.
5. Is replacing the current block going to improved the speed or is it just just related with debugging purposes? I noticed that when an error comes up in the Interpreted Function block I have to trace it back myself.
Looking forward to hear from you!

Comment: The thing with the line option is that it would be shifting to a new line and drawing it every time the function runs, while I needed the entire traveled path to be drawn, so there should be a pilling up of lines to generate that outcome, if I'm getting the functioning of the line command correctly.

Comment: There are only ever 2 line (objects): one for (x_t,y_t), which never changes; and one for (x_e,y_e).  The handle for (x_e,y_e) never changes (i.e. the line object overall doesn't change), only the XData and YData properies of the object change.  Create both of these at initialization, and store the handle of the (x_e,y_e) line for use at each time step.  Using an s-function will not really effect speed of execution, rather it allows the code to be better modularized.

Comment: Got it! I have it working, and flawlessly, if I may say so. The simulation runs as fast as if nothing is being plotted. Thank you so much for your help. Regarding the S-function, I'm having some issues with converting the function to be compatible, so I'll leave it out for now. But it's definitely something worth investigating later.
By the way, don't you have any idea about my off topic question at the end of the first comment?

Comment: Doesn't make much difference.  The first approach initially allocates one chunk of memory with x_e and y_e both pointing to it, but will allocate another chunk of memory as soon as x_e and y_e become different.  The second approach allocates both chunks of memory at the start.  They'll both take near enough to the same amount of time, it just depends whether you want one memory allocation at the start, then another later on, or whether you want both memory allocations at the start.  I'd typically go with the latter.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! That helped me understand how it works underneath. Once again, thanks for all your assistance!

Comment: Hello Alegom and @Phil Goddard,
I am facing a similar problem, where I need to update plot with changing variables.
The problem is, I want to plot rectangle around the moving point and I want the rectangle to move with this moving point.
Therefore, I also need to refresh my plot.
Can you help me?